# How to enable the IRQ on the other core?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

If my PC has two cores--CPU0 and CPU1, the IRQ of CPU0 is disabled (local_irq_disabled()). How to use a process on CPU1 to enable the IRQ of CPU0?

Answer (score 2):

Don't.
If the code on CPU0 disabled IRQs, then it needs them disabled because it's doing something important. If you magically enable them, its data structures may be corrupted and the kernel will crash.
If you have code that keeps IRQs disabled for an unreasonable amount of time, then it's buggy, and needs to be fixed.

Comment: Thank you. I am focusing on reliability about the linux kernel, so if the IRQs of CPU0 are disabled for an unreasonable amount of time(e.g. a bad spinlock may lead to this), a process executed on CPU1 would enabled the interrupt and release the lock, then recover the problem.

Comment: It's quite unlikely that it will successfully recover. More likely, it will leave some data structures corrupt, so you'll crash when trying to access them. But if you really insist - try to send NMI to the other processor (don't ask me how) and let the NMI handler do what you want.